# why are directories which are empty not removed after rmdir?

Tags: shell-script, directory, tcsh, csh

```
foreach file (`find . | awk -F/ 'NF == 3'`)
  echo $file
  set olddir = `echo $file| cut -f 1-3 -d '/'`
  echo $olddir
  set newdir = `echo $olddir  | cut -c 1-2,5-`
  echo $newdir
  mkdir -p $newdir
  mv -f $file $newdir
  rmdir $copy_datalog/*
  echo $newdir
  cp -r  $copy_datalog/* $new_datalog
```

When `cp -r $copy_datalog/* $new_datalog` is run, the files deleted with `rmdir $copy_datalog/*` are still being copied.

output of `ls -la $copy_datalog` :

```
total 10 
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 512 Oct 27 08:58 . 
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root 512 Oct 27 08:58 .. 
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 512 Oct 27 08:58 Jul2013 
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 512 Oct 27 08:58 jaa200
```

Output for `rmdir` :

```
rmdir: directory "/DATALOGARC/datalog_copy/Jul2013": Directory not empty
rmdir: directory "/DATALOGARC/datalog_copy/jaa200": Directory not empty
```

Based on my understanding, when `rmdir` runs, it removes the empty directory. So, why is it still copying the directories?

Comment: Probably because the directory is not really empty - there's a hidden file or something in it. Does the `rmdir` give an error message? Also, GNU `rmdir` seems to have a flag "--ignore-fail-on-non-empty". Do you have an alias `rm`?

Comment: im pretty sure the directories not empty since im make the directory to test the script.

Comment: can you post the output of `ls -la $copy_datalog` ? run it after `rmdir $copy_datalog/*` thx

Comment: your `rmdir $copy_datalog/*` command does not delete `$copy_catalog`.  It tries to `rmdir` every file and directory in `$copy_catalog/`.    Also,  remember to quote your variables - **always** quote variables unless you are splitting with $IFS.  Finally, `foreach` possibly implies `csh` - don't use `csh` for scripting.  or even `tcsh`.   if it's zsh, that's fine.

Comment: when im trying to rmdir only, not copying, it works and remove the empty directory. but when rmdir directory then copy after that, it copy all the empty directory. Out put `ls -la $copy_datalog ` :
total 10 
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 512 Oct 27 08:58 . 
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root 512 Oct 27 08:58 .. 
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 512 Oct 27 08:58 Jul2013 
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 512 Oct 27 08:58 jaa200
 Output for rmdir :
rmdir: directory "/DATALOGARC/datalog_copy/Jul2013": Directory not empty
rmdir: directory "/DATALOGARC/datalog_copy/jaa200": Directory not empty

Comment: I think that you are seeing only what you want to see. All this does not make much sense. Last two question to try to understand:: 1) what is the value of $new_datalog variable? In case instead of rmdir you can use rm -r to remove everything (files if there are some left, and folders) , but be careful to play with the right path

Comment: value of $new_datalog is another directory . what im trying here is to move file from copy_dsatalog to $new_datalog. But at $copy_datalog, it need to remove the empty directory only which why i used of rmdir. But after exec rmdir, the empty directory not being remove. So when copying to $new_datalog, it copy too the empty directory